# Sending and reading strings to IOT device via Bluetooth in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, iot

I'm trying to write and read to IOT device via Bluetooth in Flutter. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

flutter_bluetooth_serial is working very well with Android only...
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial